# Design Java class for Jackson when JSON key has no one name but different values

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

How to model in Java (for Jackson library) following json file where the key is the file name so it has no (constant) name

```
{
  "core/core-rwd/src/scss/_colors.scss": [
    {
      "line": 1,
      "column": 13,
    },
```

I would like to have something like

```
class MySet {
    ???? files;
}
class File {
    int line;
    int column;
}
```

What should I replace `???` with to make this compatible with Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that name is dynamic, you won't be able to map it to a POJO type field.

The solution is to deserialize the JSON to a `Map<String, Something[]>`. The `Map`'s values can still be some known type if they do map to a POJO type.

Alternatively, you can use Jackson's `ObjectNode`, a `Map`-like data structure with methods that make sense in a JSON context.

Comment: Correct. That is, instead of `MySet`, just use `Map<String,File>` as the type.